# Предметная область проекта при использовании github.com

Tags: github

**Вопрос:**

Перелистывал соглашения `github.com`, но так и не понял, могу ли я на данном ресурсе размещать не IT-проекты?

Или я был невнимателен, или одно из двух. Но максимум, что мне удалось найти по теме контента, это:

> **A.8. Account Terms**
>
> You may not use the Service for any illegal or unauthorized purpose. You must not, in the use of the Service, violate any laws in your jurisdiction (including but not limited to copyright or trademark laws).

А если я захочу размещать текущею разработку, не связанную с IT? Допустим,  разработку монографии по тензорному исчислению, корневым годографам для анализа САУ, ... да хоть грабежу корованов?

Пожалуйста, дайте линк на "нормативный документ", регламентирующий допустимую тематику контента проекта, создаваемого на `github'е`.

Речь идет о `illegal or unauthorized purpose`. Туман.

Comment: Обратили внимание на `violate any laws in your jurisdiction`? Например, если будете обучать ... (почитайте УК и вставьте сами) деятельности, то вас прикроют.

Comment: брррр "нарушать" или "обучать"??? просто мой иностранный - японский, а английский по словарю(

Comment: Насколько помню, *обучение* (т.е. предоставление исчерпывающей информации) некоторым вещам является *нарушением* УК. (только не просите меня рыться в нем).

Comment: Если бы мне оказали небольшую "лингвистическую" помощь, тупо перевод на английский, я бы смог это уточнить у администрации овервлова. Кто готов и в состоянии? Плис, плис)

Comment: И что именно тут нужно перевести *на английский*?

Comment: Ну, типа, мое письмо/обращение, которое я напишу. Один абзац.

Comment: Вот чат http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45075/ для английского

Comment: @avp, я бы с удовольствием. Но я не знаю английского. Только тучу слов с переводом.

Comment: Нарушение УК - это нечто более серьезное, чем нарушение ToS github. И последствия, которые за этим могут случиться, серьезнее, чем отключение аккаунта gitlab. Просто сам gitlab к этим последствиям уже не будет иметь никакого отношения. Это просто не связанные вещи.

Comment: * github имел в виду

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На github, помимо кода, размещают [блоги](https://github.com/mojombo/tpw) и [книги](https://github.com/OpenSFNovels/opensfnovel01).

Нет ограничения на смысл контента, который вы размещаете. Размещайте что хотите.

Что касается нормативного документа, то при регистрации в сервисе вы должны согласиться лишь с одним документом. Это [Github Terms Of Service](https://help.github.com/articles/github-terms-of-service/). Там есть некоторые разъяснения относительно того, что нельзя размещать:

### G. General Conditions

> You must not upload, post, host, or transmit unsolicited email, SMSs,
>   or "spam" messages.
>
> You must not transmit any worms or viruses or any code of a
>   destructive nature.

Однако github оставляет за собой право закрыть ваш аккаунт по любой причине:

### D. Cancellation and Termination

> GitHub, in its sole discretion, has the right to suspend or terminate
>   your account and refuse any and all current or future use of the
>   Service, or any other GitHub service, for any reason at any time.

Поэтому не важно, есть ли нормативный документ, который вы ищете или нет (а его, скорее всего, нет, кроме самого Terms Of Service), ваш аккаунт могут закрыть в любой момент по любой причине.

Тем не менее, самое страшное, что может случиться с вашим аккаунтом на Github - он будет удален без возможности восстановления.

Поэтому:

1. Размещайте что хотите.
2. Делайте бэкапы (это полезно и для IT-проектов :)

И все будет в порядке.

Comment: благодарю!!! ...